# Disqus comment as guest by default

Tags: wordpress, comments, blogs, disqus

Is there a way to by default have the Disqus comment system set to guest commenting?

On a blog my whife has, her redaers have to go trough a few steps to be able to comment as a guest and comments have gone down because of this.

Answer (score 4):

No. Currently, users need to opt in to commenting as a guest by selecting "I'd rather post as a guest", and it is not possible to disable other login options, shown here:

[image: Post as guest]

However, When guest commenting is enabled for your forum here http://disqus.com/admin > Guest Commenting > Allow guests to comment, all logged out users will have the option to comment as a guest.